# How to search for pattern in multiple lines using a regular expression

Tags: tcl

Consider the pattern is:

```
PPP(GJ)  {
           __hj_o:
         }
```

What is the regular expression match the above pattern?

Comment: You mean regex, right? In what language? tcl?

Answer (score 2):

Tcl's regular expressions can contain newlines just fine, but for anything complicated it can help to put it in its own variable instead of having it as an inline literal:

```
set RE {PPP(GJ)  {
           __hj_o:
         }}

if {[regexp $RE $someString]} {
    # We got a match!
}
```

Indeed, `regexp` would also match the above with this:

```
set RE {PPP(GJ)\s+{\s+__hj_o:\s+}}
```

because newlines are just ordinary whitespace characters (i.e., are matched by `\s` and `.`) by default. (The above REs are probably not exactly what you want; they likely need suitable patterns for the non-whitespace portions as well.)

*However,* you need to ensure that the string you are matching against has the whole thing that you want to match. If you're just feeding through one line at a time, that multiline pattern will consistently fail. This sounds obvious, but it is the easiest mistake to make.

Comment: @nandini As long as you get those multiple lines into one string, *every command* (that does matching) *can match multiple lines*. Really. (Well, it's a little trickier with Expect and the search method in the Tk text widget; those use the single-line-only matching mode by default.)